# Highlight a cell if it contains a word from another cell

Tags: google-sheets

Hi anyone can help me? Please!

I'm Using **Google Sheets**

I have a long list in column **A** of words, and I'm making a few paragraphs from this words in column **D**, but I don't want to overuse a word twice so I want a Formula should highlight in column **A** the cell with the word I used already in any cell in column **D**.
Note that column D have multiple words in each cell.

Can I explain it better? Who knows? :) If yes, let me know,

Thanks and Best
Joel Mitt

Comment: You could use an `onEdit()` simple trigger function to get all the values in column D, then get all the words in column A, then loop through every value in column A, and search for that word.  Maybe concatenate all the data from col D, since it doesn't matter what cell it's from in col D.  You just need to know if it's been used or not.  So, it can be done, but the problem is, that your basically asking someone to write the entire code for you.  Are you going to program this mostly yourself?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simpler solution but try selecting column A and click Format > Conditional formatting > Custom formula is

`=COUNTIF(QUERY(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT(JOIN(" ",D:D)," ")))}&{"",""}),"select Col1,count(Col2) group by Col1"),"select Col1 where Col2>1"),A1)`

see it working in this example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_XziNINzfygDxKVU42AqleOWlhJiEU4S44_ENH91fW0/edit#gid=0